# PCA : same explained variance ratio for different number of components

Tags: python, linear-algebra, covariance, pca, variance

I'm trying to understand PCA. I have a 3-dimensional dataset, I built two PCA models, one with 2 components, and the other with 3 components. However, I don't understand why the explained variances ratio for both PCA models is the same.

```
Model with 2 components: [ 0.60792494  0.31234679]
Model with 3 components: [ 0.60792494  0.31234679  0.07972828]
```

Comment: Assume you are using sklearn.decomposition.PCA (the question would be better formed if you included that), the documentation said: 
explained_variance_ratio_ : array, [n_components]
Percentage of variance explained by each of the selected components. If n_components is not set then all components are stored and the sum of explained variances is equal to 1.0. Basically PCA is to find all basis functions that construct the space spanned by the dataset. Each component associates with each basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data you are using is the same for both models, then were you to use all possible components, the explained variance ratio should sum to 1. In your instance, the first two components explain ~91% of the variation. Because each PCA component is orthogonal to the previous ones, any additional components you add will explain only the variance that has not yet been explained. Thus, the first 2 components of the 3 component model will explain the same amount as the 2 component model and the 3rd component will explain an additional 8% of variation.

You're using python, perhaps a good intuitive introduction and examples could be found in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html